# Unable to execute batch files with non-administrative user on windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, permissions

I have some batch files which are created by the administrator and I need non-administrative users to run them. I have given permission to the non-administrative user to read and execute to the file and the entire folder tree.
I am still not able to run the batch file, I am getting an "Access Denied" error.

Are there any more permissions that I need to set? ( These batch files start / stop windows services).

Comment: Are you getting "Access Denied" when trying to execute the .bat files, or when from within the current user context you are attempting to manipulate Windows services?  My hunch would be the latter.

Comment: I am getting Access Denied when I login as the different user and try to run the batch files. The script basically starts / stops zookeeper services.

Comment: you cannot start or stop a service if you are not administrator, even if you can run the executable.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - I see. Is there no other way in which this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `runas` as stated here: https://superuser.com/questions/973349/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-setuid

but it would require the users to know the administator password.

Another "hack": you could create a running service which would look in a given folder (say `C:\trigger`) every 10 minutes, and if it finds some file in here, then starts/stop the service and deletes the file.

Users could simply use a script that would create that file, which would start the service after a while.

Since the service just starts/stop a given service, there is no security issue.